# Inconsistency in passing by reference - how does this simple example of passing by reference work?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I had a simple question and was hoping for the underlying logic behind passing by reference.

Here's one code (let's call it Code1):

```
void fn(int& a)
{
    a = 6;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 5;
    fn(b);
    cout << b;
}
```

Here's another code (Code2):

```
void fn(int* ptr)
{
    *ptr = 6;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 5;
    fn(&b);
    cout << b;
}
```

And a pass by value code (Code 3):

```
void fn(int a)
{
    a = 6;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 5;
    fn(b);
    cout << b;
}
```

Here goes my question. Intuitively, I see that while passing by value (Code3), the values are copied ie a would just have taken/copied into itself the value of `b`. Thus, as a general rule, I see that value passed is just copied always to the called function (here fn). Even with the pointer code (ie Code2), the first line of Code 2 ensures that `int *ptr = &a;`

I don't understand how this would work in Code1. Saying that `&a = b` makes no sense. Is this an exception, or does this fit into a rule that is consistent with the cases discussed in the paragraph above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function:

```
void fn(int &a) {
a=6;
}
```

the term "&a" does not mean "the address of the variable `a`". It means "a reference called `a`". Code 1 and Code 2 are effectively the same (but note that the function in Code 2 can be passed an invalid pointer, which is (almost) impossible for Code 1).

Comment: "which is (almost) impossible for Code 1" That is mostly a semantic distinction. All compilers implements references as pointers underneath, and if you have a function like `void fn2(int *a){ fn(*a); }`, it will compile this function as simply passing the address through, no "dereference". So *effectively* you can pass an invalid reference just as easily as passing an invalid pointer. A language purist would say that dereference expression on invalid pointer is undefined behavior, so anything after is meaningless. But this is just an academic technicality and is not visible to the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

For most intents and purposes, a reference is just a pointer in disguise. Different syntax, same effect (mostly).

Comment: The only reasons you want references are a) pointers are often too general and powerful and b) we love syntactic sugar. Let the compiler stem the heavy burdens of understanding pointers.

Comment: @Deduplicator I never bought argument a. It makes pointers seem like dark magic and discourages learning about them.

Comment: If you don't actually need to perform arithmetic on the pointer itself, it eliminates one conceptual level of indirection. At about 4-5 stars, you should be thankfufl for that... Otherwise, it's certainly only for the sugar.

Comment: @Deduplicator You may want to point to different objects at different times.

Comment: @Deduplicator You said, if you don't need to perform pointer arithmetic, it's only for sugar. But you also need a pointer if you want to point to different objects with the same pointer. Reference cannot be reseated.

Comment: Build some list management code and you easily get 3, maybe even four pointers deep. But if you look closely, you never actually change the lowest level, so you can replace it with a reference, removing one conceptual level. That brainpower can then be employed in other places. That was my original statement for case a). Later i conceeded that you seldom get so much indirection in normal code. Hope it is now clearer.

Comment: @Deduplicator If you can replace 4* pointer with a reference, you can replace it with a 1* pointer, so I don't really understand, anyway I'm going to bed now!

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, in your first case what happens is that the same variable has two labels: `b`, visible within the scope of `main()`; and `a`, visible within the scope of `fn`.

You don't have to worry about what the compiler does "behind the scenes" to implement this concept.

If you mentally promote the compiler's "behind the scenes" actions to actually being imagined principles of C++, e.g.  "the reference is a pointer in disguise", then it leads you to get confused about what is actually a pretty simple concept: the ability to give multiple names to a variable.

It is nothing special being a function parameter; e.g. you could write in `main()`:

```
int a;
int &c = a;
```

which is exactly equivalent to:

```
int c;
int &a = c;
```

In both cases there is an `int` variable with two labels, `a` and `c`.